# background image not showing in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sanitize

Yes, I did search and found many examples, but none worked for me. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Need help!

I can see the image if I put in `<img>` tag, but not when I put as `background-image`. But I can see the binary image when I do inspect element.

Tried doing an example in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-image-from-rest-api-qpnspq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

HTML:

```
 <!-- This works -->
 <div class="row" style="max-width: 100%; margin-left: 1px;" >
     <img id="dashboardImage" [src]='imageBlobDataUrl' height='500' width='500' />
 </div>

 <!-- This does NOT works -->
<div class="row" style="max-width: 100%; margin-left: 1px;" [style.background-image]="image"> </div>
```

TS:

```
    @Input() imageBlobDataUrl: any;
    selectedImage: QiImage = new QiImage();

    public header:SafeHtml;
    public content:SafeHtml[];
    public image:SafeStyle;

  constructor(
          private qiImageService: QiImageService,
          private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
          private imageService: ImageService
  ) {}
  populateImageDetails(lineId, bitmapFileName) {
      this.imageService
          .populateImageDetails(lineId, bitmapFileName)
              .subscribe( (selectedImage : any) => {
                  this.selectedImage = selectedImage;
                  //let TYPED_ARRAY = new Uint8Array(selectedImage.imageData);
                  //const STRING_CHAR = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, TYPED_ARRAY);
                  //let base64String = btoa(STRING_CHAR);
                  let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + selectedImage.imageData;
                  this.imageBlobDataUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
                  this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${objectURL})`);
              });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a stackblitz example to show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Set the imageblobdataurl as the image then check

Comment: @nircraft - Added stackblitz url

Comment: @HitechHitesh - sorry, didn't get you what you are saying

Comment: @SK. added my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine when i tried your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-image-from-rest-api-qpnspq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) . You need to Fix CSS to get the image displayed on view.

Do not use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` for Style Url. So the below for thumbnail is not valid:

```
this.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL); // Do NOT Use

this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${objectURL})`); // This works fine and is Valid
```

Try to adjust the **CSS position** for your image and it will show up:

```
<div class="row" 
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute; 
  margin-left: 1px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;" 
  [style.background-image]="image"> </div>
```

Comment: OMG!!! I have been working on this since past 2 days. Thanks for pointing this out. width: 100%; height: 100%; was the thing I was missing.

Comment: @SK. happens to everyone.. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

if you try to set the background image using CSS ? like this:

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("../../yourimage");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

In the template you can use the binding to set the css class as you like

Comment: my image is coming from rest service as BLOB (binary) data, not a png/jpg file path. I also tried with worked with mnau different ways.

Comment: If you want to set a div with a background image, you need to set it in CSS, you can do it dynamically using a function it will receive a url image and set this with property biding. Take a look in this documentation [Template biding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding)

Comment: I strongly recommend the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) exercise for better understanding of angular basic resources. I always take a look

Answer (score -1):

You can just put the URL image on src even if it's on base64

```
 <img id="dashboardImage" [src]='objectURL' height='500' width='500' />
```

Comment: I already said that if I put the image in <img> tag, it works, bu tI want it as background image